# Subtracting different columns from different tables in r

Tags: r

I have created two different tables in R from a SQL database. I want to subtract one table from another to find the error. Since the two tables are from different dates, the column headings are different. The tables look like this:

```
Table X

Item | D22 | D23 | D24 | D25 | D26 | D27
A       5     6     7     4     6     9
B       4    10     3     6     8     8
C..     6     7     5     8     4     5   

Table Y

 Item | D22 | D23 | D24 | D25 | D26 | D27
A       4     8     3     8     5     10
B       4     9     4     6     5     7
C..     5     6     5     7     8     9
```

The table are 3 time periods apart, so D22 on Table X relates to D25 on Table Y and so forth. I want the final table to look like this

```
Item | t1 |  t2 |  t3 | 
A       3     1     3 
B       2     5     4 
C..     1     1     4
```

The equation for t1 is abs(D22.X-D25.Y), t2 is abs(D23.X-D26.Y), and t3 is (D24.X-D27.Y). I already have the tables set up and I am wondering if there is a merge or join function in R where I can also set up these variables in that new table.

Comment: `melt` or `gather` everything to long format, create a common key for the times (subtracting 3 from the numeric parts of the old Y column headings), join on Item and the common time key, subtract.

Comment: Or, convert the `Item` column to row names and convert both tables to matrices. Omit the columns that don't overlap, make sure the rows are in the same order, and do `abs(x_matrix - y_matrix)`. If you post the data in a nicer (copy/pasteable) way, I'll demo.

Comment: For small tables like these you could just subset and do a logical test. `dfA[,1:3] == dfB[,4:6]`. Or if you want to see absolute difference, `abs(dfA[,1:3]-dfB[,4:6])`.